# How do I make a button only available during a certain time of day in html?

Tags: javascript, html

```html
<html>
<head>
<style> 
    .bttHider {
        display: block;
        disabled: true;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <input id="bttHider" class="bttHider" type="submit"  onclick="showHidden(); showbttHidden(); this.style.display='none';" value="Add a new
notice here.">
</body>
<script>
    int h = new Date(hours)
    if 5 <= h <= 7 {
        document.getElementById('btttHider').style.disabled="false";
    }
</script>
```

So I need the input.bttHider to only be available during 6 in the morning till 8 in the morning but I'm unsure how to implement that, any help to show me what is wrong with it would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your problem might be in the javascript at the bottom. I see three `t`s in the element ID argument vs two `t`s in the HTML.

Comment: And also handle the case when that button is pressed outside that period, as someone could insert it forcefully.

Comment: Ehm, I would advise you to go with something server-side, at least for the action that will be performed. Never trust data from the client. Or for that matter trust the client to do as you want them to.

Comment: There is no disabled style. And the disabled property expects a boolean, not a string.

Comment: That's not valid JavaScript. [Lint it here](http://www.javascriptlint.com/online_lint.php).

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this, without declaring datatype and with proper date object and your script within the body tag... Also, instead on piting onclick in your html, use an event listner in your javascript. If you read uo a little on event listners and javascript in general you will be writing a much better javascript...

```
<body>
    <input id="bttHider" class="bttHider" type="submit"onclick="showHidden(); showbttHidden();" value="Add a new
notice here.">

<script>

    var h = new Date().getHours(); 
    var butn = document.getElementById('btttHider');
    if (h <= 5 && h >=7) ){
        btn.disabled=false;
    } else { 
     btn.disabled=true;
}
</script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Couple things wrong: 1) if you want it to be available from 6-8 your if statement should look like `if (h >= 6 && h <= 8)` and 2) to remove the disabled attribute remove the parenthesis and `.style` so that you have `.disabled = false`.

HTML:

```
  <input id="bttHider" class="bttHider" type="submit" onclick="showHidden(); showbttHidden();" value="Add a new notice here." disabled>
```

JS:

```
  var h = new Date().getHours();

  if (h >= 6 && h <= 8) {
        document.getElementById('bttHider').disabled=false;
  }
```

Fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/8tf46zqu/3/